# Polyfill or workarounds for ECMAScript5 new features?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, polyfills

I want to write my JS code with the new [ECMAScript5 features](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) that working today and in the future.

As not all browsers support all the features (especially IE) such as `Object.create`, `Array.isArray` or `JSON`.

I knew a few workarounds such as use `json2.js` to archieve `JSON` support. I want to know more polyfills or workarounds for the other feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at these :

https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills ( es5 shims listed in the middle)